# I can't able to Pass Values through protocol in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols

I need to pass value from `ScheduleViewController` from did select row method to `MySchedularViewController` table cell.

**Here is my protocol**

```
protocol ScheduleViewControllerDelegate {
    func mySchedule(imgIcon: [String], proName: [String], proTime: [String])
}
```

Passing values from did select row method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        scheduleViewControllerDelegate?.mySchedule(imgIcon: ["hello"], proName: [programNameArray[indexPath.row]], proTime: [programTimeArray[indexPath.row]])

        print("Row Selected")
    }
```

getting protocol in myScheduleViewController

```
extension MySchedulerViewController: ScheduleViewControllerDelegate{
    func mySchedule(imgIcon: [String], proName: [String], proTime: [String]) {
        programImgUrlArray = imgIcon
        programNameArray = proName
        programTimeArray = proTime
        print("Hello ")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.scheduleTableView.reloadData()
        } 
    }
}
```

I created two instances for the ViewController(ScheduleViewController) where I created protocol. Does it cause any problem?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: you can check it.I think its ok now

Comment: Thank you - it's much easier to read now

Comment: **Swift tip** - don't wrap your `reloadData()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` unless it's being called on a background thread.

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, are you setting `cell.scheduleViewControllerDelegate = self`?

Comment: where you are setting scheduleViewControllerDelegate ?

Comment: Iam setting ScheduleViewControllerDelegate = self  in MyScheduleViewController

Comment: class MySchedulerViewController: UIViewController {
    
  {
        super.viewDidLoad(){
        let scheduleVc = ScheduleViewController()
        scheduleVc.scheduleViewControllerDelegate = self
        
    }